# How to play SWF Files in iPhone App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, krpano

I have a requirement in my iPhone app to download SWF file and run,have tried with Webview but couldn't get sucked.
I need to download the panoramic tours and need to play in offline.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Not really possible, SWF is flash and flash it not support on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Well,actually you ran in the wrong way.Krpano has a html5 version .Set `html5:"prefer"` option to make it works on ios.